# how to use iframe in flutter to stream video from IP address

Tags: flutter, iframe, ip, video-streaming, ip-address

i already use some package like flutter web view package, but still cannot stream the video, maybe because get Cross-Origin Resource Sharing. i want to stream the video from IP address, i run it from my windows and get IP-address from my raspberry pi

code:

```
                      Container(
                          height: 200,
                          width: 500,
                          color: Colors.tealAccent,
                          child: HtmlElementView(
                            key: UniqueKey(),
                            viewType: Config.materialDetailIframeID,
                            onPlatformViewCreated: (int viewId) async {
                              await Future.delayed(
                                  const Duration(milliseconds: 500));

                              final iframe = IFrameElement()
                                ..src = 'http://192.168.18.223:8000/video_feed'
                                ..style.border = 'none'
                                ..style.width = '100%'
                                ..style.height = '100%';
                            },
                          ))
```